# vb.net: How to adress form items dynamically

Tags: database, vb.net, forms, textbox, location

I have a form in vb.net with LOTS of text- and comboboxes. Now i do want to apply some settings to them, e.g. visibility, location and so on during runtime. The information on what to apply is complex and is stored in my database together with the name of the given item, e.g. name=textbox1, visibility=true, location x = bla, location y= bla and so on.

My question is: Is it somehow possible to use the string in the field "name" to adress the object in the code like this:

```
ConvertToFormObject(name).visible=visibility
```

so that i could apply the settings with a single loop rather than hardcoding the information in the database to all the items. Also the settings should be applied spontanously, when e.g. some event triggers were triggered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can index the `Controls` collection of the form by name to get the control with that `Name` value, e.g.

```vb
Dim cntrl As Control = Controls("TextBox1")
```

This assumes that all the controls of interest are on the form directly. If they are all in the same child container then use the `Controls` collection of that container. If they might be in different containers, e.g. a `Panel` and a `GroupBox`, then you can call `Find`, e.g.

```vb
Dim cntrl As Control = Controls.Find("TextBox1", True).First()
```

Note that `Find` returns a `Control` array, because the `Name` of each control in a container must be unique but multiple containers can each contain a control with the same `Name`. Assuming that you have used unique `Name` values form-wide, you just call `First` or `Single` or index the array with zero.

Comment: Excellent John! That works for me. Thank you! Also thank you for the additional comment on GroupBoxes and Panels since i do indeed use them but with unique control names as you assumed all over the form.

Comment: Even simpler, based on your idea: I just skipped the indexation and adressed the control directly like this: Controls.FInd("Textbox1",True).First().Visible=True.